# C# Slow response times with HttpClient compared to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

For some reason when doing the same POST request with HttpClient and HttpWebRequest, HTTPClient takes 2000+ms while HttpWebRequest takes around 1000-1400 ms. 
Is this disparity normal and is there anything I can do to make the httpclient match the speed of the httpwebrequest?

I've posted code below in case I'm messing something up.

```
protected WebRequest CreateWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(EndPoint));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
    request.Headers.Add(CustomHeaders);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    return request;
}

private async Task<string> DoHttpClientPost(string method, IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
{
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
        handler.Proxy = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (var myHttpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
            myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
            myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(APPKEY_HEADER, CustomHeaders.GetValues(APPKEY_HEADER));
            myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(SESSION_TOKEN_HEADER, CustomHeaders.GetValues(SESSION_TOKEN_HEADER));
            myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json-rpc"));
            var call = new JsonRequest { Method = method, Id = 1, Params = args };
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.Serialize<JsonRequest>(call);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-rpc");
            response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(EndPoint), content);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nCalling: " + method + " With args: " + JsonConvert.Serialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(args));
        string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return jsonResponse;
    }
}


public async Task<T> Invoke2<T>(string method, IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
{
    if (method == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
    if (method.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(null, "method");
    string jsonString = await DoHttpClientPost(method, args);
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JsonResponse<T>>(jsonString);

    return jsonResult.Result;
}



public async Task<T> Invoke<T>(string method, IDictionary<string, object> args = null)
{
    if (method == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
    if (method.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(null, "method");

    var request = CreateWebRequest(new Uri(EndPoint));

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var call = new JsonRequest { Method = method, Id = 1, Params = args };
        JsonConvert.Export(call, writer);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nCalling: " + method + " With args: " + JsonConvert.Serialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(args));

    using (WebResponse response = GetWebResponse(request))
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.Import<T>(reader);
        // Console.WriteLine("\nGot Response: " + JsonConvert.Serialize<JsonResponse<T>>(jsonResponse));
        if (jsonResponse.HasError)
        {
            throw ReconstituteException(jsonResponse.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            return jsonResponse.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at what's happening on the network with something like Wireshark or Fiddler?

Comment: Yeah they have the same headers and are the same size, its very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

HttpClient should, if possible, be [reused across requests](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Have you tried isolating creating the HttpClient instance, and performing the actual request? Both creating and disposing the resources held by the instance does take time, although 1000ms sounds like a lot.

Another possible cause of slowdowns when using HttpClient or WebRequest is setting [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit too low](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit). The default is 2, so if you're doing a lot of concurrent or even several requests in fast succession, you'll end up waiting for the ServicePointManager to free the connections.